# How to get around a limit in an R function?

Tags: r, wikipedia

I am doing data analysis on the Acadie portal in fr.wikipedia.org.

I am using WikipediR::pages_in_category to make a list of the pages in the portal:

```
library(WikipediR)
portal_acadie <- pages_in_category(language = "fr", 
                                    project = "wikipedia", 
                                    categories = "Portail:Acadie/Articles liés", 
                                    limit = 500, 
                                    clean_response = TRUE)
```

**There is a limited output of 500 to the function, but I know the portal has 1900+ pages. How can I extract the remaining 1400+?**

I tried changing the `limit` argument to `limit = 2000`, but I had a warning message indicating

> '"cmlimit" may not be over 500 (set to 2000) for users.'

It only showed the first 500 pages.

Comment: Haven't checked it myself but it might be originated by Wikipedia API rate limitations and not by the package itself.

Comment: @AndreaDodet is correct:  see here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers

Comment: Maybe you can abstract the logic that figures how many pages you will need and call this function multiple time

Comment: @user2554330 Could you clarify what I would have to do within R, using the information from the page you provided?

Comment: There's nothing you can do in R.  This is a policy decision by the people who run that web site.  You'll need to contact them to find out how to do what you want to do, living within their limitations.

Comment: In other circumstances you might be able to find a way to break your query up into multiple chunks, each below the limit, but it's hard for me to see how to do that in this case. Maybe you can scrape https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portail:Acadie/Index_th%C3%A9matique and download articles within each sub-category?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! I'm starting to think I might need to explore the wikipedia API myself. It might allow me to do things the WikipediR and WikipediaR packages won't allow me to do...

Comment: I'd highly recommend using the API directly. That should allow you to find the remaining output even if you can only fetch 500 per call. The only way to increase the 500 limit is to have a Wikipedia bot or admin account. If you're after data like this, you should also consider using petscan: https://petscan.wmflabs.org/

Comment: e.g. https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?outlinks_any=&cb_labels_any_l=1&project=wikipedia&edits%5Banons%5D=both&categories=Portail:Acadie/Articles%20li%C3%A9s&search_max_results=500&cb_labels_no_l=1&edits%5Bflagged%5D=both&language=fr&edits%5Bbots%5D=both&interface_language=en&ns%5B0%5D=1&cb_labels_yes_l=1&max_sitelink_count=&doit=